# Scaffold DbContext from specific prefixed (with regex or string) tables of an existing database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, reverse-engineering

I am using `Scaffold-DbContext` to reverse engineering my existing database with EfCore 6. There I have many tables to scaffold that name as `RISK_`. Using the documents, I noticed to use `--table` pipe to specify one by one table. But it is a bit harder to use every time to determine every RISK_ prefixed table in the command.

**Is there any pipe or configuration to get that prefixed table name or define regex to use in scaffold command?**

Thanks

Comment: Try EF Core Power Tools

Comment: @ErikEJ yes I am a big fan of the EF Core power tool. But we have a few edge cases that cannot resolve using the power tool.  
for an example  https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/issues/1431, I am facing this kind of modification in ef core scaffolding. Then I am moved to `EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Handlebars` implementation. But there I blocked with generating separate IEntityTypeConfiguration classes.
Have you any idea about that as well?

Comment: Refrain from doing domain modelling with your EF Core classes

Comment: @ErikEJ yes . Now I got it your point. Thanking for advices